# IIS URL rewriting coming from outside

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I have a web application running on a IIS8 server.

My front accesses my api without issues. They are both in the same folder on the same server. The requested url looks like this : **api/customer/register**

Now I want another web app (from another domain) to access my api with this url : *https://mydomain/api/customer/register*

When I try to request my api, I get this message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'https://mydomain/api/api/customer/register'

The problem are the two **api/** in the url. How can I resolve this ?

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules> 
            <rule name="web-rewrite">
                <match url="^(?!(api\/|shibboleth|poc\/|outlook))(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="web-rewrite-files" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^web/(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="web/" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="api-rewrite">
                <match url="^(api\/)(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Try changing the url in `api-rewrite` from `api/{R:0}` to either `api/{R:1}` or `{R:0}`

Comment: Or remove capturing parenthesis from url property in match tag.
Like this `^api\/(.*)`

Comment: @AlbertVanHalen it doesn't change anything;

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy I get 404 with your solution...